# Como puedo cerrar mi aplicacion de android studio cual es el codigo de ese boton usando casos?

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando con casos segun el boton que se le de clic. Tengo varios botones pero hay uno que dice cerrar o salir ese tiene el id que muestro. Si en caso se le da clic a ese boton, me tiene que cerrar la aplicacion o en otras palabras salir de ella pero no lo hace:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnSuma, btnResta, btnProducto, btnDivision;
    private EditText numero1, numero2;
    private TextView resultado;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //enlazar los objetos con los elementos xml
        numero1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.n1);
        numero2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.n2);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        //colocar el cursor en el primer EditText
        numero1.requestFocus();
        btnSuma = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsumar);
        btnResta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnrestar);
        btnProducto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmultiplicar);
        btnDivision = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btndividir);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        //escuchar los onClick de los botones
        btnSuma.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnResta.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnProducto.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDivision.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //declaramos las variables
        String valor1 = "", valor2 = "", mensaje1="", res="";
        float num1 = 0, num2 = 0, total = 0;
        //Tomar los valores o dar mensaje de error
        try {valor1 = numero1.getText().toString();
            valor2 = numero2.getText().toString();
            //convertirlos a float
            num1 = Float.parseFloat(valor1);
            num2 = Float.parseFloat(valor2);
            //controlar el onClick según el id del botón
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnsumar:
                    total = num1 + num2;
                    mensaje1 = "SUMA: " + total;
                    numero1.setText("");
                    numero2.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.btnrestar:
                    total = num1 - num2;
                    mensaje1 = "RESTA: " + total;
                    numero1.setText("");
                    numero2.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.btnmultiplicar:
                    total = num1 * num2;
                    mensaje1 = "PRODUCTO: " + total;
                    numero1.setText("");
                    numero2.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.btndividir:
                    total = num1 / num2;
                    mensaje1 = "DIVISIÓN: " + total;
                    numero1.setText("");
                    numero2.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.salir:
                    finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //mensaje de error
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ingrese todos los datos",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //salida de datos
        resultado.setText(mensaje1);
    }



}
```

EL XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="OPERACIONES BASICAS"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Numero 1:"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="Numero 2:"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/n1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsumar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suma"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnrestar"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/n2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnrestar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resta"
        android:layout_below="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnmultiplicar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="multiplicar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnsumar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndividir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dividir"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnrestar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/n2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnmultiplicar"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/salir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="salir"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Puedes explicar lo que quieres? Te lanza algun error?

Comment: no solo cerrar la aplicacion

Comment: alvin, se mas detallista explicando. Que es lo que necesitas?

Comment: baya tengo varios botones pero hay uno que dice cerrar o salir ese tiene el id que muestro ahi baya si en caso se le da click a ese boton me tiene que cerrar la aplicacion o en otras palabras salir de ella

Comment: Edita tu pregunta e incluye el codigo del Activity y su xml para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

No le estas indicandole al boton salir el evento clic. Debes de enlazar el boton salir con el xml y luego escuchar el evento clic:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

     private Button btnSuma, btnResta, btnProducto, btnDivision;
     //...

     Button btnSalir;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


           //enlazar los objetos con los elementos xml
            //...
            btnSalir= (Button)findViewById(R.id.salir);

            //escuchar los onClick de los botones
            //...
            btnSalir.setOnClickListener(this);
      }
```

Comment: gracias eso funciono

Comment: Recuerda marcarla como aceptada si era la respuesta que buscabas

Comment: si claro solo que tengo una duda como indico que solo me muestre dos decimales como controlo eso

Comment: Eso requiere otra pregunta en el sitio. No es bueno que se traten 2 temas en una pregunta porque no ayuda a los demás que quizás tengan ese problema. Crea otra pregunta con tu inquietud para que pueda ser respondida